# Purpose of "where" keyword in constructor of a parametric type

Tags: julia, where-clause

For the Julia manual [parametric composite type example](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#Parametric-Composite-Types-1)

```
struct Point{T}
    x::T
    y::T
end
```

it is possible to write an outer constructor such as

```
Point(x::T, y::T) where {T} = Point{T}(x, y)
```

Why is the `where {T}` part needed, i.e. why isn't

```
Point(x::T, y::T) = Point{T}(x, y)
```

possible? Julia complains that `T` is not defined, but could it not figure out that `T` is a type from the `::` syntax? I am a newcomer to Julia so I might be missing something pretty basic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`T` is a variable that has to be defined. If you do not define it in `where` Julia starts looking for it in an outer scope. Here is an example:

```
julia> struct Point{T}
           x::T
           y::T
       end

julia> Point(x::T, y::T) = Point{T}(x, y)
ERROR: UndefVarError: T not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[2]:1

julia> T = Integer
Integer

julia> Point(x::T, y::T) = Point{T}(x, y)
Point

julia> Point(1,1)
Point{Integer}(1, 1)
```

Note that in this example you do not get what you expected to get, as probably you have hoped for `Point{Int64}(1,1)`.

Now the most tricky part comes:

```
julia> Point(1.5,1.5)
Point{Float64}(1.5, 1.5)
```

What is going on you might ask. Well:

```
julia> methods(Point)
# 2 methods for type constructor:
[1] (::Type{Point})(x::Integer, y::Integer) in Main at REPL[4]:1
[2] (::Type{Point})(x::T, y::T) where T in Main at REPL[1]:2
```

The point is that The `(::Type{Point})(x::T, y::T) where T` already got defined by default when the `struct` as defined so with the second definition you have just added a new method for `T = Integer`.

In short - always use `where` to avoid getting surprising results. For example if you would write:

```
julia> T = String
String

julia> Point(1,1)
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Int64 to an object of type String
```

you get a problem. As the signature of `Point` is fixed when it is defined but in the body `T` is taken from a global scope, and you have changed it from `Integer` to `String`, so you get an error.

---

Expanding on what @Oscar Smith noted the location of `where` is also sensitive to scope, and tells Julia on what level the "wildcard" is introduced. For example:

```
ulia> T1 = Vector{Vector{T} where T<:Real}
Array{Array{T,1} where T<:Real,1}

julia> T2 = Vector{Vector{T}} where T<:Real
Array{Array{T,1},1} where T<:Real

julia> isconcretetype(T1)
true

julia> isconcretetype(T2)
false

julia> T1 isa UnionAll
false

julia> T2 isa UnionAll
true

julia> x = T1()
0-element Array{Array{T,1} where T<:Real,1}

julia> push!(x, [1,2])
1-element Array{Array{T,1} where T<:Real,1}:
 [1, 2]

julia> push!(x, [1.0, 2.0])
2-element Array{Array{T,1} where T<:Real,1}:
 [1, 2]
 [1.0, 2.0]
```

and you can see that `T1` is a concrete type that can have an instance, and we created one calling it `x`. This concrete type can hold vectors whose element type is `<:Real`, but their element types do not have to be the same.

On the other hand `T2` is a `UnionAll`, i.e. some of its "widlcards" are free (not known yet). However, the restriction is that in all concrete types that match `T2` all vectors must have the same element type, so:

```
julia> Vector{Vector{Int}} <: T2
true

julia> Vector{Vector{Real}} <: T2
true
```

but

```
julia> T1 <: T2
false
```

In other words in `T2` the wildcard must have one concrete value that can be matched by a concrete type.

Comment: This answer should probably include a section about the difference between `Point{Point{T} where T}` and `Point{Point{T}} where T`

Comment: I have added a comment on the topic of location of `where`.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to take a different tack from Bogumił's excellent answer (which is 100% correct, but might be missing the crux of the confusion).

There's nothing special about the name `T`.  It's just a common convention for a short name for an arbitrary type.  Kinda like how we often use the name `A` for matrices or `i` in for loops.  The fact that you happened to use the same name in the `struct Point{T}` and in the outer constructor is irrelevant (but handy for the readers of your code).  You could have just as well done:

```
struct Point{SpecializedType}
    x::SpecializedType
    y::SpecializedType
end
Point(x::Wildcard, y::Wildcard) where {Wildcard <: Any} = Point{Wildcard}(x, y)
```

That behaves exactly the same as what you wrote.  Both of the above syntaxes (the struct and the method) *introduce* a new name that will behave like a "wildcard" that specializes and matches appropriately.  When you don't have a `where` clause, you're no longer introducing a wildcard.  Instead, you're just referencing types that have already been defined. For example:

```
Point(x::Int, y::Int) = Point{Int}(x, y)
```

That is, this will reference the `Int` that was already defined.

I suppose you could say, but if `T` wasn't defined, why can't Julia just figure out that it *should* be used as a wildcard.  That may be true, but it introduces a little bit of non-locality to the syntax, where the behavior is drastically different depending upon what happens to be defined (or even exported from a used package).

Comment: Indeed - I did not think that the naming might be a source of confusion, but you are right! One small comment for the potential readers - `T` does not have to be a type (e.g. like in arrays, where one of the parameters is an integer indicating the dimension), so you are referencing to names that already have a binding when you try to define a method.

Comment: Thank you for this angle! I was aware that ```T``` is just an arbitrary convention, but missed that it could also refer to a variable in the outer scope. This solves the confusion: ```where {T}``` seems redundant because it does not give information about the type ```T``` (in the sense that it doesn't, for example, say ```where {T<:Real}```) - but it _does_ define ```T``` afresh in the local scope.